# New instance of android emulator starting on each run

Tags: android, macos, adb, ddms

I've checked every single related post (I know there're a lot) but still no one common solution works for me.
Almost every time users solve this issue by:

```
adb kill-server
sudo start-server
```

But not in my case. I do that and nothing happens. Nevertheless I cannot run my App in emulator, I can do it in normal physical device and it works!

I'm on latest OS X (ML). Latest for today sdk, adt, eclipse(kepler). Everything is up to date. 
When I check adb devices, it's empty. Or when I switch to DDMS - same. 
When running an app, it's starting displaying normal messages in console:

```
[2013-07-03 18:59:42 - NewApp] ------------------------------
[2013-07-03 18:59:42 - NewApp] Android Launch!
[2013-07-03 18:59:42 - NewApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-07-03 18:59:42 - NewApp] Performing vista.Start activity launch
[2013-07-03 18:59:49 - NewApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Hihi'
```

But after, the unlock screen is shown, the app appears to be not installed on the emulator.

I've tried different API levels and also reinstalled all eclipse, adt,etc. As well as deleted and recreated the virtual device.

The thing I've noticed is that the debug mode is OFF in the emulator. And if I change it and run again, it still OFF.

I'm really sorry for reposting, but I couldn't find exactly the same problem description.

PD: The other thing I've noticed is that sometimes eclipse prompts for something to allow or not with warning window. But it appears/disappears so fast that there's no time to read and answer.

Do I have all correct paths?

```
~/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb
~/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator
~/.android/avd/
/Applications/eclipse
```

Comment: try initiating a device from avd externally (not from eclipse) and check whether DDMS or adb devices list the devices or not??

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I've checked and after
"./emulator @Hihi"
nothing is detected in DDMS nor ADB

Comment: tell me one thing when you start emulator from eclipse is there any error occur in DDMS console saying that the connection to emulator has been lost?

Comment: Nothing, DDMS is clean because no devices are there. Console is the only who speaks and with normal messages.

Comment: keep your emulator on.. and reset your adb from device view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep your emulator on.. and reset your adb from `device view`

Comment: At first it said:
`[2013-07-03 20:13:17 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF`
`[2013-07-03 20:13:17 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1`
But then emulator appeared in devices list! 
However app is not started:
`Uploading App.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'`
`Failed to install App.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout`
But this might be my problem... 
Thank you a lot!